# Meaning of 匙加減 in this sentence

Tags: sentence, reading-comprehension

> 簡単な匙加減で殺せてしまうほど、衰弱し

How does 簡単な匙加減で exactly work here?

"With a simple amount?"

Answer (score 2):

The word 匙加減 basically refers to "(adjusting) amount (of sugar, salt, etc)", but by extension, it commonly implies someone's "(often empirical, casual and/or unfair) discretion/decision".

> 俺なんて社長の匙加減ひとつでクビになる。
> A person like me can be fired at the drop of a hat by the boss.
>
> そういうのって彼女の匙加減(しだい)ですから。
> That's all up to her discretion. / That's how she (casually) handles these things!

So (Aの)簡単な匙加減で(Bを)殺せてしまう means B's life is at A's mercy, and A doesn't need to get serious to kill B at all.